Texture Bake Comes Out Blobby
I'm trying to bake some high poly grass meshes (image 1 below) into a transparent albedo texture & normal map to then use as alpha cards in game development. The square plane behind the tufts of grass is what I'm using as the bake plane.
The problem is, whenever I bake, each grass blade comes out as a blob with no definition (image 2 is the bake result). It's like somebody used a thick brush in MS Paint & traced over each blade. The normal map also comes out blobby. I spent hours playing around with the settings, and researching on the internet, but nothing seems to work.
The only thing that comes a bit closer to giving the correct results is increasing the resolution of the texture, which makes the disgusting looking blobs thinner.
I'm using old hardware, which makes the GPU cycles greyed out in the render settings, forcing me to use CPU. Could this be the reason?
If the solution is obvious and the problem is due to something really stupid I'm doing, just go easy on me, I'm fairly new to blender lol


I somehow missed the very obvious Margin parameter in the bake settings, which happened to be the culprit.
Setting the Margin to 0 pixels removed the awful padding.
